# Saving pix from Google camera to SD card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, camera, storage

I have tried all the suggestions in the forum, but to no avail...

What I have:
Galaxy S4, 8GB internal, 64GB SD card, Omega ROM with Android 4.3 (TouchWiz); has Samsung camera AND Google camera (with Photosphere) which I prefer much more than the Samsung camera.

Samsung camera makes it easy to store pix on ext. SD card. Cannot find any setting or way to do the same with Google camera. Even tried deleting DCIM on internal SD card, hoping I would be asked where I wanted to store pix. But DCIM and subfolders were just recreated on the internal SD card.

With only 8GB internal, I need to clear more space out. That's why this is so important. Any help?

Comment: it seems i cant answer due to less than 10 reputation. if you are rooted you could try the app FolderMount.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the Google Camera app does not natively support saving pictures/videos/panoramas to SD Card.  I am guessing that this goes with Google's general stance against SD cards in general.  If your device is not rooted, you are stuck with having to manually move the images/videos.

For rooted devices, there is a work-around to this limitation.  [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) allows various modules to override many stock firmware options without using 3rd-party ROMs.  It should also work on custom ROMs, but that isn't "officially" supported by the framework's developer.  You will need the [Pictures2SD module](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-pictures2sd-v1-0-6-makes-camera-t2408880), which makes all media from various camera apps (including Google Camera) to be automatically saved to the DCIM folder of the SD Card.

Xposed Installer app is not directly available via the Google Play Store, so after [rooting your S4](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=how%20do%20i%20root%20my%20galaxy%20s4) (looks like you are already rooted, since you're running a custom ROM), you will need to allow side-loading of applications via `Settings -> Security -> Unknown sources`, download and install the APK from [here](http://dl.xposed.info/latest.apk), and activate it according to these instructions:

> **Installation of the framework:**
>
> 1. Download the Xposed Installer APK and install it
> 2. Launch the Xposed Installer, go to the "Framework" section and click on "Install/Update"
> 3. Reboot
> 4. Done!

After that, the installation of modules is pretty straight-forward:

> **Installation of any modules:**
>
> 1. Download .apk (e.g. via the
>      builtin repository browser) and install it
> 2. Launch the Xposed Installer
>      and go to the "Modules" section (you will also get there if you click
>      on the notification warning you that the module is not enabled yet)
> 3. Enable the module by checking the checkbox
> 4. Reboot
> 5. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Install a file manager like ES File Explorer and manually move the captured images to a directory on your SD card. Only way around this ridiculous restriction I believe. You would have to do this each time you use the camera obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround (I'm not sure if it works on Samsung devices).
On my Moto G with Kitkit 4.4.4, I go to Settings > Storage > Move Media > Pictures.

...and voila. Google's Camera takes better pictures so I don't mind moving them every once in a while over to my SD.

Answer (score 2):

Saving pictures to any 3rd party app is forbidden. It leads to a CTS fail even if a ROM builder provides an app with it. Therefore, I don't think Google Camera app has that function. You should change `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml` by adding:

```
group gid="media_rw"
```

under

```
permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

After that, find an app with the function of saving to the external SD card.